# Variable in multi-line expression not resolving

Tags: karate

I have the following scenario that matches the response against a multi-line expression that contains a variable. This variable is defined in `karate-config.js` and is present because the test succeeds up to the final step.

```
Background:
  Given url $baseUrl

Scenario: Fetch Root
  Given path "/"
  When method GET
  Then status 200
  And match header Content-Type == $halJson
  And match response ==
  """
  {
    "_links": {
      "user": {
        "href": "$baseUrl/user"
      }
    }
  }
  """
```

How can I get the `baseUrl` variable replaced with the real value in the `match response` step?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the help of a co-worker I found something that worked

```
  And match response ==
  """
  {
    "_links": {
      "fpu": {
        "href": '#(baseUrl + "/fpu")'
      }
    }
  }
  """
```